# Using Find method to find the column value of a variable date in a named range from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: **Short version (longer explanation below):**

I have a variable date value in Sheet8.Range("s1")

I have a named range in Sheet3 called "HolidaySchedule"

I am trying to use the variable date from Sheet8 to find the corresponding column of the date in "HolidaySchedule" where dates are listed in one row.

I'm trying to get the column number in "HolidaySchedule" where the variable date appears stored in a value (e.g. Dim iTargetCol as Integer)

```
Sub Scheduler()
'The below code sample correctly grabs the date value (e.g. 21/08/2019) and correctly references the named range location 
Dim vCurrentDate As Variant
Dim rCurrentDateCol As Range
Dim lCurrentDateCol As Long
Dim iTargetCol As Integer
Dim rRng As Range

vCurrentDate = Sheet8.Range("s1").Value

Set rRng = Sheet3.Range("HolidaySchedule")
```

**Long version:**

Our team uses Excel sheets to allocate work schedules. I'm trying to create some VBA code so that it automatically creates a work schedule for our team based on a date entered in a different sheet.

I'm new to VBA and trying to use the find method to locate the date of one sheet to the corresponding date in a named range of a different sheet. I can't seem to get VBA to allow me to use the .Find to locate the date in the named range. Ideally, I'm able to locate the column number of the date from the different sheet that's located in the named range (example code below)

Sheet8 includes a date listed in cell S1

Sheet3 includes a list of dates for the corresponding month of the date listed in cell S1

The named range of Sheet3 called "HolidaySchedule" (C5:AJ9) has the dates listed horizontally across row 5 (but this may change): namely F5:AJ5 (the first few columns are for the names/position/etc)

The dates in F5:AJ5 are calculated using the first day of the month and each corresponding cell to the right is just the value of the cell to the left +1 (for instance: the formula in Cell G5 is F5+1)

The dates in F5:AJ5 are listed in Chinese text corresponding to the month and the date (e.g. 8月5日 which translates to 8th Month 5th Day = Aug 5)

For example purposes, Cell s1 in Sheet8 has the value of 21/8/2019.
Sheet3 F5:AJ5 has Aug 1 in cell F5 (actual text: 8月1日）, Aug 2 in cell F5 (actual text: 8月2日).

I'm quite proficient in using "regular" excel coding language and have tried to use a similar Application.Match in VBA to find the column number of the corresponding date in the named range, but that doesn't seem to be working as well.

I've tried on stackoverflow to find similar problems with finding dates in ranges of cells that contain dates but their solutions don't seem to work for me for some reason.

I've also taken a look at the Excel help on how the find function accepts its different parameters but can't seem to get it to work.

I originally thought that the cells in Sheet3 F5:AJ5 were not properly formed as values but if I copied and pasted the values into a blank row, they appropriately show up as 43678, 43679, 43680, etc

```
Sub Scheduler()

Dim vCurrentDate As Variant
Dim rCurrentDateCol As Range
Dim lCurrentDateCol As Long
Dim iTargetCol As Integer
Dim rRng As Range

vCurrentDate = Sheet8.Range("s1").Value

Set rRng = Sheet3.Range("HolidaySchedule")
```

> 'NOTE - Only 1 of either attempt a) or attempt b) or attempt c is active at a time. If a is active, the code for attempt b and attempt c is commented out

Attempt :

1. using Application.Match to find the date in the named range

   ```
   lCurrentDateCol = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(vCurrentDate)), rRng, 0)
   ```
2. using the .Find method after looking on Stackoverflow

   ```
   'Note I've also tried ThisWorkbook.Sheet3.Range(rRng).Find(.......)
    Set rCurrentDateCol = rRng.Find(what:=CDate(vCurrentDate), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rCurrentDateCol Is Nothing Then
     iTargetCol = rCurrentDateCol.Column
   End If
   Message iTargetCol
   ```
3. using the .Find method after looking on Stackoverflow

   ```
   Dim cell as Range
   For Each cell In rRng
       Set rCurrentDateCol = rRng.Find(what:=CDate(vCurrentDate), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)
           If Not rCurrentDateCol Is Nothing Then
               iTargetCol = rCurrentDateCol.Column
               Exit For
           End If
   Next
   MsgBox iTargetCol

   End Sub
   ```

> **Expected:** return column number within the named range once it finds the date from the other sheet in this named range (i.e. supposed to return 24)
>   e.g.

21/8/2019 as Sheet 8.Range("s1").value;

In Sheet 3
Cell F5 contains value of 43678 (equiv to Aug 1, 2019 formatted as "8月1日")

Cell G5 contains value of 43679 (equiv to Aug 2, 2019 formatted as "8月2日")
...
Cell Z5 contains value of 43698 (equiv to Aug 21, 2019 formatted as "8月21日")

Actual results if using attempt a:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Actual results if using attempt b and c:

> Msgbox "Not found"

Comment: Thank you NickCoder for helping me edit the readability :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub Scheduler()

vCurrentDate = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value

Set rRng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("HolidaySchedule")

lCurrentDateCol = Application.Match(vCurrentDate * 1, rRng, 0)

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C2").Value = lCurrentDateCol

End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
If you have trouble with the variable types, either delete them altogether (and don't forget to delete "option explicit" at the start of your code. Or set them like this:

```
Sub Scheduler()

Dim vCurrentDate As Long
Dim rCurrentDateCol As Range
Dim lCurrentDateCol As Long
Dim iTargetCol As Integer
Dim rRng As Range

vCurrentDate = 1 * (Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value)

Set rRng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("HolidaySchedule")

lCurrentDateCol = Application.Match(vCurrentDate, Range(rRng.Address), 0)

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C2").Value = lCurrentDateCol

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample & the screenshot! Looks like it works in your sample, but when I tried your code though I still get a "runtime error '13' - Type mismatch" on the line that runs the Application.Match

I checked that vcurrentdate is set as variant, lcurrentdatecol is set as long, and rRng is set as Range.

Comment: Then the problem is very probable due to the variable type. You an either completly remove explicitly setting the variable types. If you get an error if you remove them, simply delete "option explicit" at the start of your code. Otherwise you need to set the correct type, like this in my EDIT Answer.

Comment: Used Ctrl+F (and manually looked) and couldn't find Option Explicit written anywhere (And I made sure VBE's setting of "Require variable declaration" is unchecked)

Copied and pasted the exact declarations in your edited code into my code but still get the error at the application.match line.

Copied and pasted the code into the new workbook and still get the same error